# Why is my font color not being applied?

Tags: html, css, ajax, colors

If I set the font like so on a label:

```
<label id="lblrptgenprogress" class="invisible redfont">Report generation list is being constructed...</label>
```

...it works (I see the text in red after I remove the "invisible" class).

However, if I try to set the color like so in another label:

```
<label id="testsettingproduceusage" class="midnightbluefont"></label>
```

...with no text in the label to begin with, but adding it dynamically later, it doesn't work - the dynamically added text remains the default black. Why? How can I get it to respect the assigned class?

I give the label some text in an AJAX call this way:

```
. . .
success: function (returneddata) {
    var nextgendate = returneddata.testsettings.NextGenDate;
    var nextfromdate = returneddata.testsettings.NextFromDate;
    var nexttodate = returneddata.testsettings.NextToDate;

    var verbiage = 'If you save the current configuration, the Produce Usage report would next be sent on ' +
        nextgendate +
        ' and emailed to ' +
        addressees +
        '; the report would cover data from ' +
        nextfromdate +
        ' to ' +
        nexttodate;
    $("#testsettingproduceusage").append(verbiage);
    document.body.style.cursor = 'pointer';
},
. . .
```

The CSS is:

```
.redfont {
    color: red;
}

.midnightbluefont {
    color: midnightblue;
}
```

### UPDATE

Specificity it is, as can be seen by the comments:

```
.midnightbluefont {
    /*color: midnightblue;*/ <= doesnt' work
    /*color: #191970;*/ <= doesn't work
    /*color: #191970 !important;*/ <= works
    color: midnightblue !important; <= works
}
```

Comment: css specificity most likely, but we can't tell for sure from what you've provided.

Comment: Try using hex instead of names for your colors. I doubt that the issue, but it could be. midnightblue is `#191970` and red is `#FFFFFF`

Comment: Red works; no reason to change that.

Comment: Specificity it is (see update); if you want to make that an answer, Kevin B, I'll mark it as such.

Comment: @amflare, `#FFFFFF` is white.

Comment: Dammit... IDK what I was thinking, you are right.

Comment: It happens!  take a break and relax!

Comment: !important isn't the right way to solve it

Comment: @KevinB; theoretically/philosophically, maybe so; pragmatically, it is (it works). That's really about all I care about (99.83%, anyway).

Comment: Feel free to post an answer with it, i'd suggest instead making the css selector more specific.  but.... that's going to depend on whatever is setting the color to black.

Comment: Probably some Bootstrap labyrinthe.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The brute force way to work it is either this:

```
.midnightbluefont {
    color: midnightblue !important;
}
```

...or this:

```
.midnightbluefont {
    color: #191970 !important;
}
```